Periodicity of matrix exponentials
Let $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and suppose we are trying to compute an integral of the form
$$ I = \int d^n x \, f(x). $$
Here, I am interested in performing a change of variable $x \rightarrow \exp\left(i \theta_A T^A\right) \, v$ where $v$ can be taken as a vector with only one non-zero component, e.g.
$$ v = (0, \dots, \lambda). $$
The matrices $T^A$ constitute a subset of the $\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$ generators of the Lie algebra of $SO(n)$ (with $A=1,\dots,\frac{(n-1)(n-2)}{2}$) and $\theta_A$ denote the components of some real vector $\theta$.
Assuming that the integral is taken over $\mathbb{R}^n$, I am trying to determine the domain over which $\theta$ should be restricted for the change of variable to be consistent. More generally, this raises the question of the periodicity of the matrix exponential of $i \theta_A T^A$. I have been putting quite an effort in searching for answers but could not find any references discussing the periodicity of matrix exponentials.
So here my question is twofold: regarding the particular case depicted above, how to determine the domain of integration for the components of $\theta$ ? And more generally, would there be any references in the literature discussing the periodicity of matrix exponentials ?
